# Why does .save() still take up time when using transaction.atomic()?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, transactions

In Django, I read that `transaction.atomic()` should leave all the queries to be executed until the end of the code segment in a single transaction. However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected:

```
import time
from django.db import transaction
my_objs=Obj.objects.all()[:100]
count=avg1=0
with transaction.atomic():
    for obj in my_objs:
        start = time.time()
        obj.save()
        end = time.time()
        avg1+= end - start
        count+= 1
print("total:",avg1,"average:",avg1/count)
```

Why when wrapping the `.save()` method around a start/end time to check how long it takes, it is not instantaneous?

The result of the code above was:

```
total: 3.5636022090911865 average: 0.035636022090911865
```

When logging the SQL queries with the debugger, it also displays an `UPDATE` statement for each time `.save()` is called.

Any ideas why its not working as expected?

PS. I am using Postgres.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably just a misunderstanding here about what `transaction.atomic` actually does. It doesn't necessarily *wait* to execute all the queries -- the ORM is still talking to the database as you execute your code in an atomic block. It simply waits to *commit* (SQL `COMMIT;`) changes until the [successful] end of the block. In the case there is an exception before the end of the transaction block, all the modifications in the transaction are not committed and are rolled back.

Comment: So are there any performance benefits?

Comment: @JohnMc yes, there is definitely a potential performance impact. It may be a positive or negative impact, big or small, depending on the specifics of the queries. _Atomic_ transactions usually add overhead.